# In a Spring MVC 3.1 application, how should I use the request's locale to control string formatting by an HttpMessageConverter?

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization

In a Spring MVC 3.1 application, how should I use the request's locale to control string formatting by an HttpMessageConverter?

I have this enum representing soil types (excerpt):

```
public enum Soil {

    SAND("0.35"),
    PEAT("0.70");

    private Double porosity;

    Soil(String porosity) {
        this.porosity = new Double(porosity);
    }

    @NumberFormat(pattern = "0.000")
    public Double getPorosity() {
        return porosity;
    }

}
```

I also have a controller for accessing soil properties. This is serving ajax requests triggered when a different soil type is selected.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/soil/*")
public class SoilController {

    @RequestMapping(value="{id}/porosity")
    public @ResponseBody Double getPorosity(@PathVariable String id) {
        Soil soil = Soil.valueOf(id);
        return soil.getPorosity();
    }

}
```

As I understand it, by using @RequestBody, Spring converts the returned Double to a response body by using an
HttpMessageConverter. This works fine, but the response string is always formatted using the default locale. For instance, a GET request to /soil/PEAT/porosity will result in a '0.7' being written to the response body.

However, most visitors have 'nl' as their preferred locale, expecting a decimal comma instead of a decimal point. In this case, I'd like the response string to be formatted as '0,7'.

I can add an HttpServletRequest parameter to the handler method's signature to determine the request's locale, but don't know how to pass this information to the HttpMessageConverter - a MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter in this case (*). I know it is possible to configure the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter bean by overriding the defaults in the  tag, but how do I make it aware of the request locale?

(*) DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotat ion.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Written [0.7] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJac ksonHttpMessageConverter@145240a]

**Working solution**

As @CodeChimp remarked (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15074077/1343409), i18n formatting is best handled by a view.

I changed the handler method to

```
@RequestMapping(value="{id}/porosity")
public String getPorosity(@PathVariable String id, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    Soil soil = Soil.valueOf(id);
    model.addAttribute("doubleValue", soil.getPorosity());
    return "basevalues/double";         
}
```

and added a simple JSTL view double.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/plain;charset=UTF-8" %>
<fmt:formatNumber type="number" value="${doubleValue}"/>
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ResponseBody annoatation instructs Spring to take whatever it is your returning, and plop it into the response body.  It does it 1-to-1, there is no conversion.  For instance I have used that annotation to return Binary image data, CSV files, etc.  If you want to return a number that is formated for a particular locale, then you will need to do the check in your getPorosity() method and make the proper modification there.

**Edit to add info**

My understanding of the HttpMessageConverter is that it is used to convert to/from HTTP request/responses.  HttpMessageConverter is, itself, just an interface with many implementations.  The proper implementation is chosen based on the request/response headers and the type of return you are using.  For instance, if the request specifies it accepts application/xml or text/xml, then the MarshallingHttpMessagingConverter is used to convert the return to the proper XML format.

However, the @ResponseBody annotation allows one to circumvent the conversion.  This annotation is basically indicating to Spring "don't worry about converting the return type, just take what I am returning and shove it into the response body."

I do not believe that any of the classes that implement HttpMessageConverter are concerned with locale at all.  Their only concern is to take the return type and convert it to the proper form for transport.  Handling i18n-related items, which would be those reliant on the locale, are view-related concerns, and in my experience best handled in the view.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Still, the Spring docs at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody imply handler methods may return any type and leave the conversion to String to an implementation of HttpMessageConverter. I'm happy with a pragmatic solution, but it seems odd having to do the String formatting in the handler and being forced to return a String.

Comment: Your last remark made me realise I was probably trying to use the HttpMessageConverter for a problem it's not intended to solve. Of course you are right: if you need to format a number, it's best to use a view. I've appended a working solution to my original question. Thanks again for putting me on the right track!